# Exception while calling JS interoperability in Blazor Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: error loading dynamically imported module

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am currently using a blazor server side project and I have this project structure
BlazorServer Project

```
Entities-Models Project
Shared Library
Components
 -Components
 -wwwroot
 --Some Exported functions in .js
```

and here I have assigned a task which contains the imported method

```
 protected  Task<IJSObjectReference> moduleTask;
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var dirs =Directory.GetDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());//here doesnt show the wwwroot folder but only the one form the blazor server project
            
            moduleTask =  JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./wwwroot/InterOpLib.js").AsTask();
            

        }
```

and during initialization of this moduleTask it has an exception inside
"JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method."

and then when the actual method is called

```
protected async Task PrintMessage(string title, string message)
        {

            try
            {
                await (await moduleTask).InvokeAsync<string>("showAlert", title, message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

it throw exception message "Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: 'error loading dynamically imported module"

and the console says

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: error loading dynamically imported module

```
  Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: error loading dynamically imported module

     at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
     at WebApp.Components.Components.RegisterBase.PrintMessage(String title, String message)
     at WebApp.Components.Components.RegisterBase.CreateUser()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

it is worth noting I am calling this method on a button click event

edit: even after assigning it in the AfterRenderedAsync, it keeps throwing and exception  "Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: 'error loading dynamically imported module" and the code looks like this

```
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                moduleTask = JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./wwwroot/js/InterOpLib.js").AsTask();
            }
        }

        protected async Task PrintMessage(string title, string message)
        {

            try
            {
                await (await moduleTask).InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert", title, message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

here is the js function

```
export function showAlert(title,message) {
    alert(title, message);
}
```

Comment: Did you add this to `OnAfterRenderAsync` as mentioned in the error message?

Comment: @Marius well i havent but i think that once the screen has loaded it should have been already rendered?, but how am i supposed to call it on this method when I need it on a button event/

Comment: The `OnAfterRenderAsync` lifecycle method handles all after render logic as the name implies. Meaning, JS can only be loaded/invoked after this time. `IJSRuntime` depends on this. Make sure to add it when `firstRender == true`. But I advise importing modules by calling a JS function or adding the import to the top of `app.js`

Comment: @Marius i moved the js file into the blazor server project's wwwroot folder but it doesnt shows the exception when reading the file's module but... when trying to invoke it says  "error loading dynamically imported module"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't append "wwwroot" in your path to the module. (js file should be inside client's wwwroot folder.)

```
moduleTask =  JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./InterOpLib.js").AsTask();
```

Also like @Marius said in the comment it's better to load the module inside `OnAfterRenderAsync` and use `InvokeVoidAsync` if your js function does not return result.

```
@code {
    private IJSObjectReference module;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>(
                "import", "./InterOpLib.js");
        }
    }

    protected async Task PrintMessage(string title, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showAlert", title, message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo project on github: https://github.com/Jimmys20/InteropDemo

Comment: well i tried doign what you suggested but also doesnt show InvokeVoidAsync(with the generic) method. and it keeps throwing Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: 'error loading dynamically imported module  even with the correct signature the method isnt called..
'

Comment: I created a demo project on github: https://github.com/Jimmys20/InteropDemo

Comment: @Dmitris Maragkos I have checked your project but somehow at server side it blocks any script on the load of the project now... i think that is a reason it cant  load said script ands it redirects to this page for further information : https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options in facct checking that it cant find the file on the server when it makes a http GET  request

Comment: oK i found that after enabling CORS (just in case) and then using the path without using wwwroot on the file's path i got it to read it  "./js/InterOpLib.js" (the parent dir is wwwroot)